# How to handle very numbers that are "too small to represent as a normalized machine number"?

Tags: numerics, special-functions, machine-precision

I will preface this by saying that I am not very familiar with Mathematica whatsoever. That is why I am asking this here even though I have found a few forum posts that might provide the solution to my problem.

Essentially, I am trying to compute a division by a massive number, and I'm running into underflow issues. The code in question is:

```
ReplaceAll[(Gamma[0.5]^2^
      x (Gamma[
       1/2^(1 - x) + 
        n/x]/(Gamma[1/2^(1 - x)] Gamma[0.5 + n/(x 2^x)]^2^x)))/
  2^n, {x -> 2, n -> 2000}]
```

and I am getting the following output

```
9.8696/(1148130695274254524232833201177681984022317702088695200477642\
7368257662613923703138566594863165062699184459646389874627734471189608\
6305533142593135616665318539129989145312280000688779148240044871428926\
99006348624478161546364638836394731702604<<119>>\
1670662583052200813223628129176126788331720659899539641812702177985840\
4042159853183251540889433902091920554957783589672039160081957216630582\
7553804255837260155283487864194320545089152757838826251754355288008228\
42770817965453762184851149029376) is too small to represent as a \
normalized machine number; precision may be lost."
```

I certainly don't need to keep all precision places, maybe only up to 5 or 6 decimals places, so I imagine the solution is somehow telling Mathematica to only keep that level of accuracy but I am unsure how to do this?

Comment: try replacing 0.5 with 1/2

Comment: You can also use ``.5`10`` instead of just .5

Comment: to put the above comments into context since you mentioned you're unfamiliar with mathematica: it distinguishes between exact numbers and approximate numbers. So, `1/2` is interpreted as exact, and `0.5` as approximate. Mathematica further splits approximate numbers into *machine-precision* & *arbitrary-precision numbers*, the latter of which can have a user-specified *precision* or *accuracy*. This is done by entering the number followed by a backtick and then the number of digits of desired precision, e.g. ``0.5`10`` for 10 digits of precision—or two backticks for digits of accuracy instead.

Comment: You might find the "Exact and Approximate Results", "Numerical Precision", and following sections of [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html) helpful. And welcome to Mathematica SE! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the replacement of `0.5` with `1/2` that was already suggested in the comments, note that when you are computing things that involve gamma functions for positive arguments, it is often better to recast everything in terms of the log gamma function:

```
With[{x = 2, n = 2000}, 
     N[Exp[2^(x - 1) Log[Pi] - n Log[2] + LogGamma[2^(x - 1) + n/x] -
       LogGamma[2^(x - 1)] - 2^x LogGamma[1/2 + n/(x 2^x)]]]]
   19851.336032351905
```